# Import external RTF file for TRichEditViewer?

Tags: inno-setup, rtf

I'm using `TRichEditViewer` on a custom page in an Inno Setup script. Is it possible to read an external RTF file into a variable, and use that variable as the content of the viewer? Or do I have to keep the actual RTF code in the script?

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Your follow-up question: [LoadStringFromFile into compiled script (so available on system that doesn't have the file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26315825/850848)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `LoadStringFromFile` to read an `RTF` file into a string. From the Inno [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_loadstringfromfile):

> Prototype:
>
> > function **LoadStringFromFile**(const FileName: String; var S: AnsiString): Boolean;
>
> Description:
>
> > Loads the specified binary or non Unicode text file into the specified string. Returns True if successful, False otherwise.

You should be able to define a `string` type variable for *ANSI Inno Setup* or `AnsiString` type variable for *Unicode Inno Setup* using something like:

```
var
#ifndef UNICODE
  rtfstr: string;
#else
  rtfstr: AnsiString;
#endif
```

Then in the code:

```
LoadStringFromFile('filenamehere.rtf', rtfstr);
```

And then use code similar to what is below. In this example assume `oRichViewer` is a `TRichEditViewer` object:

```
oRichViewer.UseRichEdit := True;
oRichViewer.RTFText := rtfstr;
```

This should have the effect of putting `rtfstr` which we loaded from the file earlier into the `TRichEditViewer` .

Comment: Beautifully clear, and does exactly what I asked for. Thank you!

Comment: Whould file `filenamehere.rtf` be loaded at compile time?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to copy your `.rtf` file to the temporary folder before displaying it, and want to fill variable with RTF content at compile time - you can use [Inno Setup Preprocessor](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/).

First, create a macros `ReadFileAsStr`:

```
#pragma parseroption -p- 

#define FileHandle
#define FileLine
#define FileName
#define Result
#sub ProcessFileLine
  #define FileLine = FileRead(FileHandle) 
  #if Len(Result) > 0 && !FileEof(FileHandle)
    #expr Result = Result + "#10#13 +  \n"
  #endif
  #if FileLine != '\0'
    #expr Result = Result + "'" + FileLine + "'"
  #endif
#endsub
#sub ProcessFile
  #for {FileHandle = FileOpen(FileName); \
    FileHandle && !FileEof(FileHandle); ""} \
    ProcessFileLine
  #if FileHandle
    #expr FileClose(FileHandle)
  #endif   
#endsub

#define ReadFileAsStr(str AFileName) \
  Result = '', FileName = AFileName, ProcessFile, Result
```

And use it:

```
var
  rtfstr := {#emit ReadFileAsStr("path_to.rtf")};
```

This works for most RTF files, but some characters inside RTF can broke this code. To fix this you need to escape `'` and may be some other characters inside `ProcessFileLine` sub.

Comment: Maybe you should start the answer by explaining that it really does not do, what OP has asked for, and why you chose this solution.

Comment: I think my answer do exactly what OP had asked for. And this is the alternative solution. I added more explanations to my answer.