# How to load an RTF file content into Inno Setup TNewMemo?

Tags: inno-setup, rtf, pascalscript

The builtin license page of Inno Setup allows to embed RTF file content into it. Is it possible to load RTF contents into `TNewMemo`? I am using `TNewMemo` inside my custom page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot load RTF into `TNewMemo`, you have to use `TRichEditViewer`.

See [Import external RTF file for TRichEditViewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26209200/850848)